# Where can i find the XMPP soure code to develop like Openfire,Prosody IM

Tags: xmpp

I deployed XMPP(openfire) on my eclipse IDE and get it work and developed the Chat Application.
But I need to know the where we can find the actual source of XMPP since openfire implemented on it.I have to create new application like openfire,ejabberd,Prosody IM etc...

Answer (score 0):

you can find source code of Openfire in their gihub repo

https://github.com/igniterealtime/Openfire